# How to adjust the font size of the lower bar titles?

Tags: ios, core-plot

So I've got a graph that's been put together using core plot, but can't seem to figure out how to change the font size on bottom title labels. Has anyone ran across this before? If you'd like I can add the code, but I thought that this would be quite simple...Thanks in advance!
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! The text can be set with the following:

CPTMutableTextStyle *xAxisTextStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
xAxisTextStyle.color = [[CPTColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:1];
xAxisTextStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica-Bold";
xAxisTextStyle.fontSize = 5.0f;